# screenshot showing dimensions 2880x1800 but resolution 144x144

Tags: macbook-pro, resolution, screen-capture

[image]

I am trying to take some high quality screenshots on my 13" MBP for a website - they need them to be as high resolution as possible (at least 1000px wide) - when I take the screenshot (command+shift+3) and look at the info in Finder it shows dimensions of 2880x1800 but a resolution of 144x144... what is the difference and can I take screenshots at a higher resolution somehow?

Answer (score 2):

Dimension is the actual height and width of the image in pixels.

Resolution (or DPI) is the number of pixels in a square inch.

Comment: So if they say the "resolution" higher than 1000px wide am I good? I'm assuming they are referring to dimensions? how else can I get a resolution of 1000px wide?

Comment: They mean dimensions. The term "resolution" is often used (incorrectly) in place of "dimensions".